# Serial comm from a sensor to the heltec wifi kit 8?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have a sensor (HuskyLens vision sensor) that has a UART connection.
I'm trying to establish a serial connection to the Heltec Wifi Kit 8, to read the output from the sensor.

The serial connection fails to get established. Maybe I am selecting two pins on the breakout board that do not support serial communication, or ones that are conflicting with some function of the Wifi Kit 8.

I am using the sample code from HuskyLens, only modified to change the RX/TX pin numbers.
Has anybody been able to establish a serial connection to the Heltech Wifi Kit 8?

```
#include "HUSKYLENS.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

HUSKYLENS huskylens;
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 6); // RX, TX
//HUSKYLENS on Nano TX: green wire --> D7 pin --> 7, RX: blue wire --> D8 pin --> 8
// HUSKYLENS on Wifi Kit 8: TX: Greenwire:  RX Pin -> 25, RX blue wire --> TX pin --> 26
void printResult(HUSKYLENSResult result);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(57600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.listen();
  //Wire.begin();
  while (!huskylens.begin(mySerial))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Begin failed!"));
    Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the \"Protocol Type\" in HUSKYLENS (General Settings>>Protocol Type>>Serial 9600)"));
    Serial.println(F("2.Please recheck the connection."));
    delay(100);
  }

  //pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  //digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  //delay(1000);
  //digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  //delay(300);
  //digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

  //digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  Serial.println("Done init.");
  huskylens.writeAlgorithm(ALGORITHM_FACE_RECOGNITION);
  // huskylens.writeAlgorithm(ALGORITHM_OBJECT_TRACKING);
  // huskylens.writeAlgorithm(ALGORITHM_OBJECT_RECOGNITION);
  // huskylens.writeAlgorithm(ALGORITHM_LINE_TRACKING);
  // huskylens.writeAlgorithm(ALGORITHM_COLOR_RECOGNITION);
  // huskylens.writeAlgorithm(ALGORITHM_TAG_RECOGNITION);


}

void loop() {

  if (huskylens.requestLearned())          //request blocks and arrows tangged ID != 0 from HUSKYLENS
  {
    // Serial.println("###################################");
    //Serial.println(String() + F("Count of learned IDs:") + huskylens.countLearnedIDs()); //The count of (faces, colors, objects or lines) you have learned on HUSKYLENS.
    // Serial.println(String() + F("frame number:") + huskylens.frameNumber()); //The number of frame HUSKYLENS have processed.

    // Serial.println("#######");
    //Serial.println(String() + F("Get all blocks and arrows. Count:") + huskylens.countBlocks());
    for (int i = 0; i < huskylens.countBlocks(); i++)
    {
      HUSKYLENSResult result = huskylens.getBlock(i);
      printResult(result);
      delay(100);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("$$$");
  }
}

void printResult(HUSKYLENSResult result) {
  if (result.command == COMMAND_RETURN_BLOCK) {
    Serial.println(String() + F("Block:xCenter=") + result.xCenter + F(",yCenter=") + result.yCenter + F(",width=") + result.width + F(",height=") + result.height + F(",ID=") + result.ID);
  }
  else if (result.command == COMMAND_RETURN_ARROW) {
    Serial.println(String() + F("Arrow:xOrigin=") + result.xOrigin + F(",yOrigin=") + result.yOrigin + F(",xTarget=") + result.xTarget + F(",yTarget=") + result.yTarget + F(",ID=") + result.ID);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Object unknown!");
  }
}
```

Here's the pinout of the board https://www.bastelgarage.ch/image/cache/catalog/Artikel/420521-420530/420526-39-800x800.jpg An observation: I see there's an RXD0 and an TXD0 , but I see a TXD1 without a corresponding RXD1.